# find the min and max of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ subject to the given constraint $x^4+y^4=32$

Tags: calculus

Hi I'm struggling to find the minimum value for this problem. I've found that $\lambda = \pm \frac 18$ and my max of $8$ works in my answer box,but my negative value of $-8$ is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $x^2+y^2$ will not be negative if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers

Comment: Please show your work in a little more detail and we may be able to find the problem.

Comment: How are we supposed to find the mistake in your calculations if you don't share them?

Comment: note $x^4+y^4 = (x^2+y^2)^2 -2x^2 y^2$ so the question can be the same as what is the minimum and maximum value of $v:=z+w$ if $z^2+w^2 =32$ and $z,w>0$ so we have $v=z+\sqrt{32 -z^2}$ now just differentiate and get $v'=1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{32 -z^2}}$ and when $v'=0$ $z=4$ so $w=4$ and $v=8$ note this is the maximum value cause $v'(0)<0$ and $v'(5)>0$

Comment: to get the minimum value we need to find the least point in the curve $v=z+\sqrt{32 -z^2}$ we proved that $v$ is increasing at $(0,4)$ the the least point in this interval is at $z=0$ and $v=\sqrt{32}$

we proved that $v$ is decreasing at $(4,\sqrt{32})$ the the least point in this interval is at $z=\sqrt{32}$ and $v=\sqrt{32}$

Comment: @pie The minimum of $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{x^4+y^4 +2x^2 y^2}=\sqrt{32 +2x^2 y^2}$ comes when $2x^2y^2=0$ (it can never be negative) i.e. when $x=0$ or $y=0$

Comment: @Henry this is a clever way of showing that but i used the more "usual" and easy way that anyone would do

Answer (score 2):

We have $$(x^2+y^2)^2\le 2(x^4+y^4)=64$$ Therefore $x^2+y^2\le 8.$ The equality holds iff $x^2=y^2.$  Hence $4x^4=64,$ i.e. $x^4=16.$ Thus $x=\pm 2$ and $y=\pm 2.$ Summarizing, the maximal value is equal $8$ and is attained at four points $(\pm 2,\pm 2).$

Similarly $$ (x^2+y^2)^2\ge x^4+y^4=32$$ and the equality holds iff $x=0$ or $y=0.$ Thus the minimal value is equal $4\sqrt{2}$ and is attained at four points $(\pm 2\sqrt[4]{2},0)$ and $(0,\pm 2\sqrt[4]{2}).$

**Remark** Another solution can be done by applying the polar coordinates $x^2= r\cos\theta$ and $y^2=r\sin \theta,$ with $0\le \theta\le {\pi\over 2}.$ Then $r=4\sqrt{2}$ and $$x^2+y^2=4\sqrt{2}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta) \\ =4\sqrt{2}\,2\sin {\pi\over 4}\cos \left ({\pi-\theta\over 4}\right )\\ =8\cos \left ({\pi-\theta\over 4}\right )$$ The maximal value is attained for $\theta ={\pi\over 4}$ while the minimal value for $\theta =0$ or $\theta ={\pi\over 2}.$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$

$g(x,y)= x^4+y^4-32=0$

$2x=4\lambda x^3$

$2y=4\lambda y^3$

$1=2\lambda x^2$

$y/x=y^3/x^3$

$u=y/x$

$u^3=u\implies u\in \{0,1,-1\}$

$y=0\cdot x\implies x=2^{5/4}\implies f(x,y)=4\sqrt{2}$

$y=x\implies x^4=16\implies x\in \{2,-2,2i, -2i\} : f(x,y)=8$

You can only get positive numbers if $x$ and $y$ are real.

---

Alternatively:

$(x^2+y^2)^2=x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2=32+2x^2y^2$

$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{32+2x^2y^2}$

So a minimum value occurs if either $x$ or $y$ is zero: $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{32}$.

$y^2=\sqrt{32-x^4}$

$x^2+y^2=x^2+\sqrt{32-x^4}=g(x)$

$g'(x) = 2x + \frac{-4x^3}{2\sqrt{32-x^4}}=0$

$4x\sqrt{32-x^4}-4x^3=0$

$32-x^4=x^4$

$16=x^4\implies x\in\{-2,2\}$

Answer (score -1):

Due to the symmetry of the set-up, the obvious candidates are $x = y$ and $x = 0$ or $y=0$

And since every factor is sqared what works for $(x,y)$ works for $(\pm x, \pm y)$

$(x,y) = (2,2)$ satisfies the constraint and $x^2 + y^2 = 8$
$f(\sqrt[4]{32},0) = \sqrt {32} = 4\sqrt 2$

We might consider squaring the objective function, because since $f(x,y) >0$ and if $(f(x,y))^2$ is maximized (or minimized) then $f(x,y)$ will be maximized (or minimized).

$z^2 = (f(x,y))^2 = x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2y^2$

Using the constraint
$z^2 = 32 + 2x^2y^2$

$x^2y^2$ is minimized when $x^2y^2 = 0$ confirming our earlier thoughts, and again appears to be maximized when $x = \pm y$

Lagrange multipliers

$F(x,y,\lambda) = x^2 + y^2 - \lambda (x^4 + y^4 - 32)$

$\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} = 2x - 4x^3\lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} = 2y - 4y^3\lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = x^4 + y^4 -32 = 0$

$x(2-4x^2\lambda) = 0$

$x = 0$ already discussed above.

Assuming $x\ne 0$ then $\lambda = \frac {1}{2x^2}$

$2y - 4y^3\lambda=0$ has similar implications.

Assuming neither $x$ nor $y$ are $0.$
$\frac {1}{2x^2} = \frac {1}{2y^2}\\
x^2 = y^2\\
x = \pm y$

Again, as investigated above.